# Webalizer not picking up on server-side redirects

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webalizer

I'm using Webalizer on an intranet, and I want statistics for clicks on outbound links. I set up the links to point to a simple ASP redirection page -
each link resembles "redirect.asp?url=http://outsidesite.com". But Webalizer is not tracking the redirections. Is there a setting in the Webalizer config file that needs to be changed? Or do I need to set up the redirection differently?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - I used a META refresh in my ASP page instead of a server-side redirect. The server-side code puts the query string's URL in the refresh's CONTENT value.